# putMapping elasticsearch index not found exception

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am just trying to create an index using putMapping and am fairly certain this is a syntax issue. The elastic client is working for .index and .search commands, so I do not believe the setup of it is the issue. Rather it is something with my putmapping code. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. A little description of what I am trying to do. I have searched an index, and found that it does not exist. I catch the error and test to see if it equals "index_not_found_exception". If so, I need to create the index. Everything below the "..." is inside the .catch.

```
"use strict";
let config = require("./config"),
    soap = require("soap"),
    elastic = require("elasticsearch").Client(config.routeHost);
...
 if (error.body.error.type == "index_not_found_exception") {
        console.log("no index");
        elastic.indices.putMapping({
            index: "ppvevents",
            type: "ppvObject",
            body: {
                properties: {
                    name: {type: "string", index: "not_analyzed"},
                    hdid: {type: "integer"},
                    sdid: {type: "integer"}
                }
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            console.log("Response: ", response);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("putMapping Error: ", error);
        });
    } else if(error.body.error.type != "index_not_found_exception") {
        console.log("error: elasticsearch client search");
        console.log(error);
    }
```

The console response is below:

```
vagrant at localhost in /vagrant on master!
± node index.js
9000
no index
putMapping Error:  { [Error: [index_not_found_exception] no such index, with { resource.type=index_or_alias resource.id=ppvevents index=ppvevents }]
    status: 404,
    displayName: 'NotFound',
    message: '[index_not_found_exception] no such index, with { resource.type=index_or_alias resource.id=ppvevents index=ppvevents }',
    path: '/ppvevents/_mapping/ppvObject',
    query: {},
    body:
        { error:
            { root_cause: [Object],
                type: 'index_not_found_exception',
                reason: 'no such index',
                'resource.type': 'index_or_alias',
                'resource.id': 'ppvevents',
                index: 'ppvevents' },
            status: 404 },
        statusCode: 404,
        response: '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"ppvevents","index":"ppvevents"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"ppvevents","index":"ppvevents"},"status":404}',
toString: [Function],
toJSON: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 3):

If the index does not exist, `putMapping()` won't help, you need to call [`indices.create`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-create) instead. `putMapping` can only be used to add a new mapping type to an already existing index.

Replace your putMapping call with this:

```
    elastic.indices.createIndex({
        index: "ppvevents",
        body: {
            mappings: {
               ppvObject: {
                  properties: {
                     name: {type: "string", index: "not_analyzed"},
                     hdid: {type: "integer"},
                     sdid: {type: "integer"}
                  }
               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, that seems to be working in terms of not creating an error, but I get no response or anything from the elastic server..I just get "no index" and no response, no error.

Comment: Well it s' not clear what you're doing before that... What do you see in the ES logs?

Comment: Val- I reset the logger level to DEBUG, looking at them right now, and I only see the error for IndexNotFoundException[no such index] which is expected at this point. Is there a better setting to put the logger at for more info?

Comment: Are you sure that your code gets executed at all? Do you see "no index" being printed in the console?

Answer (score 0):

new version of elasticsearch.js already removed the `elastic.indices.createIndex`, you need to use `client.indices.create`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is applicable to ElasticSearch 7.14. So, in order to create an index and also add an explicit mapping, you would need to invoke:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/employee
```

with body:

```
{
    "settings": {},
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "age": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "role": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    },
    "aliases": {} }
```

Here, I have created an empty index named `employee` with the given mappings. The same can be achieved through `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` v7.14 with the below code:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.indices.CreateIndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.client.indices.CreateIndexResponse;

CreateIndexRequest cir = new CreateIndexRequest("employee");
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("properties", fieldMap);//fieldMap is another map containing the value for the `properties` key of the request body
cir.mapping(properties);
CreateIndexResponse cirs = esClient.indices().create(cir,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```